# How to plot highest price of higher timeframe and view it on lower timeframe charts

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to see the highest price of last 5 days on 4h chart and maybe other lower timeframe charts. The function that I found in coding reference: `highest(source, length)` seems not taking interval as a parameter. I came from mt4 which having this feature. So how do we do this in pine script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `security` function:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true )
s = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", highest(5))
plot(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   //@version=5
   indicator("line1" , overlay =true)
   s = request.security("Kucoin:BTCUSDT", "W", high) // 1 Day
   t = request.security("Kucoin:BTCUSDT", "W", low ) // 1 Day
   plot(s)
   plot(t)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?